# Do you know a harmless exe file that copies itself into a file?

Tags: virus, virus-removal, c++

I'm doing a simple project where I read an exe file and if I find a virus that I already know, I erase it from the file. I have to test it with a virus (I'm looking for something harmless) that insert itself into a file but I haven't found anything. Right now i am using an already infected file but i do not have the file that infects other files. The virus I do not already know just pass thru :S but i was asked to detect a virus that i do already know and that does something you can see (like a message).

Comment: Why not a coded string? Why does it have to be an actual virus?

Comment: Have you seen the EICAR file?

Comment: Do you want a virus or a harmless file? How are you "removing a virus from a file"? That may make the file useless (not that it was too useful being infected, though).

Comment: Viruses aren't bombs about to go off at a moments notice.  As long as you don't execute the code, nothing bad will happen.

Comment: What are you doing with a virus you didn't know before? Let him pass thru?

Comment: I know i can use a coded string but they asked me to use an actual virus and that I execute it first to show it does something (it would just show a message).
I will remove just the code of the virus because i already have the code of it, I know it sounds silly but this is the first approximation of the project.

Answer (score 3):

Metasploit has ways to embed executables in other files. You can use it to launch calc.exe, for your example.

The full detailed manual is [here](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/wiki/How-to-use-msfvenom), but it might take a while for you to get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

A harmless executable that copies (at least part of it) would be a zipper tool that creates an self-unzipping executable archive.

These tools are not so much en vogue today as the have been for obvious reasons.